# How come the postfix user can't even read its own files?

Tags: permissions, users, postfix

I have a Postfix configuration file. Let's assume it's named `/etc/postfix/somefile.cf`. I have run the following command as root to change ownership of the file to the `postfix (105)` user:

```
root@server:~# chown postfix:postfix /etc/postfix/somefile.cf
```

I can even confirm this succeeded with:

```
root@server:~# stat /etc/postfix/somefile.cf
  File: `somefile.cf'
  Size: 153         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 787112      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  105/ postfix)   Gid: (  108/ postfix)
Access: 2013-10-03 20:29:33.738464160 -0700
Modify: 2013-10-03 20:01:35.410464508 -0700
Change: 2013-10-03 20:29:58.482464670 -0700
 Birth: -
```

However, the `postfix` user **cannot access this file**. Watch what happens when I attempt to read its contents:

```
root@server:~# sudo -u postfix cat /etc/postfix/somefile.cf
cat: /etc/postfix/somefile.cf: Permission denied
```

What makes this even weirder is the fact that the file has permissions `0644` - so *anyone* should be able to read it. What's going on here?

---

**Edit:** I should also clarify - this is a stock installation of Ubuntu Server 12.04 32-bit.

Comment: Can world/others read the file? or just postfix user?

Comment: @Braiam: Yes, other users can.

Comment: Does `postfix` have enough rights to access `/etc/postfix/` in the first place?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: Yes, that directory has `0755` permissions.

Comment: I assume `/etc` is +x as well? Do you have something like SELinux running?

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -ld /etc /etc/postfix /etc/postfix/somefile.cf` and `lsattr -d /etc /etc/postfix /etc/postfix/somefile.cf`. Does anything appear in the system logs?